# Airflow could not find beeline

Tags: hive, airflow, beeline

I have an airflow dag that uses beeline to execute queries. Everything was working well,then system has to reboot due to blackout. After that airflow couldn't connect to beeline. The error says 
**[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beeline': 'beeline'**.
But beeline is installed in the same server where airflow runs. What could be the reason. Can anybody help me for this.
I can execute same **beeline -u** command outside airflow in command line. And it could connect to beeline.

Comment: how are you running it?

Comment: @Bommu were you able to find a fix for this issue? I am facing something similar